# Forgot password button firebase iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to create a forgot password button in my app, with Firebase, but it works just if I write the email for which I want to change the password in the code, this is the "bad" line of code.

```
Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: "email@email"
```

What should I do to modify the password of an account without write the email in the code? The problem is that a registered user can't reset his password if I do not write his email address in the code, it works just for the given email address
Following there is the complete code

```
@IBAction func resetPasswordTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var loginTextField: UITextField?
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Recovery", message: "Please enter your email address", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        if loginTextField?.text != "" {
            Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: ("email@email") { (error) in
                if (error == nil) {

                    self.showErrorAlert(title: "Password reset", msg: "Check your inbox to reset your password")

                } else {
                    print(error)
                    self.showErrorAlert(title: "Unidentified email address", msg: "Please re-enter the email you registered with")
                }
            }
        }
        print("textfield is empty")

    })
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) -> Void in

    }
    alertController.addAction(ok)
    alertController.addAction(cancel)
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) -> Void in
        // Enter the textfiled customization code here.
        loginTextField = textField
        loginTextField?.placeholder = "Enter your login ID"
    }
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func showErrorAlert(title: String, msg: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)}
```

Comment: It's a little unclear as to what you are asking; are you saying that if you include the email address string in your code it works but you don't know to get the email otherwise?

Comment: the problem is that a registered user can't reset his password if I do not write his email address in the code

Comment: I think this is by design, firebase sends password resets through emails, because I'm assuming the user signedUpWithEmailAndPassword(). Are you asking how to allow a user to reset their password immediately in the app?

Comment: You need to ask the user to enter the email they registered with in the first place, you then use that email as the parameter for *withEmail*.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, your question is a bit unclear. You must provide an email to send a password reset email. You can't use anything else, unless you strictly write functions to do a lookup for the Username/user/userId to find the email. Which would be a bit unnecessary.

Heres an example I used in my App

```
{this.state.showPasswordReset ? <div>
                <p>Input the email you signed up with, and we will email you directions to reset your password.</p>
                <form >
                    <TextField
                        hintText="email"
                        floatingLabelText="email"
                        multiLine={false}
                        rows={1}
                        name='email'
                        type='text'
                        value={this.state.email}
                        onChange={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                    />
                </form>
                <RaisedButton label='Send Password Reset Email' onClick={this.sendPasswordResetEmail.bind(this)} primary={true} type='submit' />
                {/* <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#757575', margin: 5 }} block onPress={this.sendPasswordResetEmail.bind(this)}>Send Password Reset Email</Button> */}
            </div>
                : <div>
                    <p>Forgot your password? Reset it <p style={{ color: 'red', textDecorationLine: "underline", }} onClick={() => this.setState({ showPasswordReset: !this.state.showPasswordReset })}>here</p></p>
                </div>}
```